# Postgres select all data via relation

Tags: postgresql, select

If `parent`s have `child`ren, and `child`ren have `book`s they've read, how do I know all the `book`s read by all the `child`ren of a parent?

Basic setup:

```
CREATE TABLE parent(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE child(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  parent INTEGER REFERENCES parent(id) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE book(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  readBy INTEGER REFERENCES child(id) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Insert some data:

```
INSERT INTO parent (name) VALUES
  ('Bob'),
  ('Mary');

INSERT INTO child (parent, name) VALUES
  (1, 'Stu'),    -- Bob has children Stu and Jane
  (1, 'Jane'),
  (2, 'Greg'),   -- Mary has children Greg and Bella
  (2, 'Bella');

INSERT INTO book (readBy, name) VALUES
  (1, 'Crime & Punishment'), -- Stu has read C&P and Goodnight Moon
  (1, 'Goodnight Moon'),
  (2, 'The Singularity'),  -- Jane has read The Singularity and 1fish2fish
  (2, 'One Fish Two Fish'),
  (3, 'Narnia');           -- Greg has read Narnia (Bella read nothing)
```

How do I formulate a `SELECT` query involving "Bob" as a parameter and get all the books read by his kids?:

```
( 'Crime & Punishment', 'Goodnight Moon', 'The Singularity', 'One Fish Two Fish' )
```

The same query, except involving "Mary" should give only the one book read by "Greg", who is her only child who has read anything:

```
( 'Narnia' )
```

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Disclaimer: I'm sure this question must have been asked before but I wasn't able to find it :(

Comment: my postgres starts serials at 1.

Comment: You're right, mine does too - I'll edit to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain `join`s

```
select book.name 
from book
join child on book.readby=child.id
join parent on child.parent=parent.id
where parent.name='Bob';
```

Or if you want the results as an array/list
This is unusual, usually results as rows like above are more useful but you appear to be asking for a single-line result.

```
select array_agg(book.name)
from book
join child on book.readby=child.id
join parent on child.parent=parent.id
where parent.name='Bob';
```

Note: the results could appear in any order.

Comment: This works great! I don't need the array format (I think I confused you by the syntax I used to demonstrate my desired result) but knowing about `array_agg` is useful too